# Buttons and tables not visible in tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have tried to add a scrollbar through canvas and added a frame named **frametwo** in canvas. I am adding a few buttons and a table in that frame but nothing is visible. If I add all these things in the root then they become visible. I have tried different things but nothing worked.
Here is the code that I wrote

```
import myvariant
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from pandas import DataFrame
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

rsid_list=[8,9,5,5]

mv = myvariant.MyVariantInfo()


def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    app = info(main_window)
    main_window.mainloop()

class info:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('VCESS-ExAC')

        self.root.geometry('1600x800+0+0')

        self.root.configure(background='light grey')

        main_frame = Frame(self.root)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=0, pady=0)
        main_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=1600, height=800)

        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        my_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scroll.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.config(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox(ALL)))

        self.frametwo = Frame(my_canvas)

        my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frametwo, anchor='nw')

        table1 = LabelFrame(self.root, text="Retreived Data")  ################
        table1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=0, pady=0)  ###################
        table1.place(x=40, y=250, width=250, height=380)
        table = ttk.Treeview(table1, height="8")  #################

        table['columns'] = ['rsID']
        table.column('#0', width=120, minwidth=25)
        table.column('rsID', anchor=W, width=120)

        table.heading('#0', text='Serial No.', anchor=W)
        table.heading('rsID', text='rsID', anchor=W)

        for i in range(len(rsid_list)):
            table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=i, text=i + 1,
                         values=(rsid_list[i]))



        table.place(x=0, y=0)  ##########################
        # VERTICAL SCROLLBAR
        yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(table1, orient=VERTICAL, command=table.yview)  #############
        yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')  ##################

        # HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR
        xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(table1, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=table.xview)  ###################
        xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x')  #######################

        table.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)  ##############
        table.pack(side=LEFT)
        btn_download = Button(self.frametwo, text='Save File',
                              font=("Times New Roman", 14, 'bold'), bd=3, relief=RIDGE,
                              cursor='hand2', bg='#154857', fg='white', activeforeground='white',
                              activebackground='#154857')
        btn_download.place(x=190, y=640, width=120)

        btn_graph = Button(self.frametwo, text='Graph',
                           font=("Times New Roman", 14, 'bold'), bd=3, relief=RIDGE,
                           cursor='hand2', bg='#154857', fg='white', activeforeground='white',
                           activebackground='#154857')

        btn_graph.place(x=530, y=640, width=120)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Looking forward for any possible solution.

Comment: did You pack the frame itself? also please reduce the code to [mre]

Comment: I have reduced it to minimum possible now.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of unused imports in the code example. Also, you create an instance of `MyVariantInfo` which you neither define nor use.

Comment: `place`, `pack` and `grid` are three different `Layout Managers` - when you use `pack` then don't use others. Using `pack` and `place` for the same widget is wrong or at least useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the buttons inside `self.frametwo`. You are using `place`, which means that the buttons don't affect the size of the frame. Since you don't give `self.frametwo` a size, it defaults to one pixel wide and one pixel tall. Therefore, the frame is essentially invisible and thus all buttons inside the frame are invisible.

You can easily see this by switching to using `pack` or `grid` for the buttons. When you use `pack` or `grid`, the parent frame by default will grow or shrink to fit its children. Thus, using either of these for the buttons will cause the frame to grow just big enough to show the buttons.

> I am adding ... a table in that frame but nothing is visible.

You are not adding the table to the frame, you are adding it to the root window. If you want to add it to the frame, you must use the frame as its parent. And again, you should probably not use `place`. `place` is almost never the right choice unless you are prepared to do a lot of extra work to make sure widgets are visible and responsive to changes in widget size, font size, display resolution, etc.